# Sticky Selection Mode has no effect on random proportional editing in UV Editor

Tags: texturing, uv

After UV mapping the default cube, I have

[image]

I keep the `Sticky Selection Mode` setting in the UV Editor header on `Shared Location` and enable proportional editing with `Proportional Editing Falloff` set to `Random`.

Then, if I move the selected vertex with <kbd>G</kbd>, all the other vertices come apart.

[image]

Is there any way to keep the vertices together?

Comment: I was thinking the edges have to be stitched together, but I've done that and it still doesn't work. Oddly enough, it works with all other falloff types.
Either this falloff has this particular effect because it is random, or there's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Sticky *Selection* mode is for, well, **selections**. What it does is make it so that when you select one vertex, it also selects the one the are on the *same* position.

So it doesn't, and furthermore *shouldn't*, make what you want.